# Android Listview clickable textview conflict

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have made an Listview populated with list_row_layout.xml(which is populated with json serializable class), i have clickable textview and onclick changing text from "Accept" to "Accepted". But when i click it on first listview item, another textview listview items below are changing. Here's some photos to descibe you better

[image: Before clicking the accept textview]

[image: after clicking accept in first row]

Activity class

```
     feedListView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, feedList));
```

adapter class

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private ArrayList<FeedItem> listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context mContext;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> listData)
{
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.headlineView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.confid);
        holder.approve = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.approveTV);

        holder.approve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View argView)
                {
                    holder.approve.setText("accepted");
                }
            }
        );

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    FeedItem newsItem = listData.get(position);

    holder.headlineView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getTitle()));
    holder.reportedDateView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getContent()));

    holder.approve.setTag(newsItem);



    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView approve;
    TextView headlineView;
    TextView reportedDateView;
    ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

textview code

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@id/approveTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pressed"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Accept"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#0D98BA"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write some tracking position functionality which remember the position which you have changed and make sure that only  text of  position changed .

Answer (score 0):

you must set id to each row, and save it in one array,like integer and when you click on one row you must change the value of that, and in changing text or anything you must check the value of that row,if `0` then set default and if `1` then so what you want: my idea is create `int[]` with length of that is size of your list,

first you must define you int[] like below and set to zero every index.

```
    int[] selected = new int[listData.getsize()]
```

something like this in getview:

```
    holder.approve.setId(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getId());
```

and after `else` statement in `getView`:

```
  if (selected[position] == 0)
  {
     // set default
  }
  else
  {
   // any changing that you want 
  }
```

and in onClick:

```
    selected[holder.approve.getId()] = 1;
    // any change that you want
```

Comment: The listview is populated with json array from web, and one of the json array object is ID, i have that in serializable class, can you give me a example?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:-

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);

        holder.headlineView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.confid);
        holder.approve = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.approveTV);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    FeedItem newsItem = listData.get(position);

    holder.headlineView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getTitle()));
    holder.reportedDateView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getContent()));



    holder.approve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View argView)
                {
                    holder.approve.setText("accepted");
                }
            }
        );



    return convertView;
}
```

Thanks!!